# getting error while running hdfs dfs command

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir /tmp
```

```
WARN fs.filesystem failed to initialize file systemhdfs://dev-cluster:8020: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: dev-cluster
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is saying you have no host known to the DNS server setup by your client that's named `dev-cluster`.

If you're trying to use an HDFS nameservice, then you've not fully configured the `hdfs-site.xml` for the command to use a nameservice

Comment: sorry for the late reply, thanks for answer i was able to solve it by following this.